# How to create a template vector for a templated object? VS is throwing C3203

Tags: c++, templates

Hello I have created a template

Below is the header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Airplane {
private: 
    T model;
    int counter; 
public:
    Airplane(T model);
};
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Airplane.h"
#include <string>

template <class T>
Airplane<T>::Airplane(T model) {
    if (&model != NULL)
        this->model = model;
        this->counter = 1;
}
```

Then created a set template that can accept any data type or my created template Airplane but the set must contain unique objects.

set header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class set {
private:
    vector <T> setvector;
public:
    set();
    void insert(T obj);
};
```

set .cpp file:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "set.h"
#include <iterator>

template <class T>
set<T>::set() {

    class vector<T>::iterator vi = this->setvector.begin();
}

template <class T>
void set<T>::insert(T obj) {    
    if (this->setvector.empty()) {
        this->setvector.push_back(obj);
    }
    else {
        class vector<T>::iterator vi = this->setvector.begin(); 
        bool flag = false;
        while (vi != this->setvector.end()) {
            if (*vi == obj) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            vi++;
        }
        if (flag == false)
            this->setvector.push_back(obj);
    }
```

in the main method when i tried to use the set using int or doulbe it works perfectly, however when i try to instantiate a new set using my template "Airplane", VS throw Error

```
C3203   'Airplane': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type.
```

I have tried to create a specialization for my template but still c++ will not accept it since it seems like it is a template. I have tried using `template <template <class> class T>` in the set template but still did not work.

Comment: `(&model != NULL)` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should not use

```
  using namespace std;
```

in header files.

2) Templates should be defined in header files, not in cpp files.
You may read about it 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

3) Your issue,  it seems you try to call

```
  set<Airplane> s;
```

`set` is a class template which takes some type.
Your code works for `int` and `double` because they are types.
`Airplane` **is not a type**. It is template, you can get
type from template by instantiating it, so you need to provide
one argument in template arguments list (`<>`) for Airplane.

```
  Airplane<int>
```

For instance, if you want to have `set` of `Airplane<int>` objects, write:

```
  set< Airplane<int> > mySet;
```

In addition, you have to add `operator==` for comparing Airplanes objects.
Without it you will get errors in this line 
      `if (*vi == obj) {` in `insert` method.